# Monitoring columns from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, monitoring

I'm currently working on a MySQL database being executed on a server and which is constantly receiving similar data from two different sources. I need to know when there is a big difference between the data on them. For example, if I'm storing coordinates, I want to raise an alert when there is a difference of more than 30 meters between the data from the two sources at a certain time. Also I want a client terminal to receive this alert.

I think there are two approaches there: having a trigger in the database alerting me when that condition is fulfilled or through a Python script in the same server performing queries and checking for the condition.

In any case, I'm not sure which one would be the more optimal approach, or if there is any already defined method or tool for doing this.

Comment: A script allows you to change the searchconditions (e.g. looking for 40m-changes that happened in the past). A trigger can be faster (you can e.g. just log the relevant data and in your app query this smaller log table). If you update data instead of inserting it, you will probably need a trigger anyway to keep your old data in a history table. Also, generally, a client will not receive a notification, it has to query on its own (e.g. if there's a new row in a log table). Btw, "font" is an interesting synomym for "(data) source" (in your language), had to think a bit about what it could mean.

Comment: It is true that I would need to change the search conditions, so maybe I should consider using the script. Also, I use only inserts. 
About the "font", sorry and thank you for your clarification! I'll take it into account. I've edited the OP.

Comment: Just to clarify: you can of course design your trigger so you can adapt your search condition later on (e.g. instead of logging warnings, precalculate every distance and query for that), and it's only relevant if you want to find "old errors" with new conditions. But generally, a script is more flexible (e.g. you might want to check for name changes you didn't prepare your trigger for) and is more robust against delayed inserts (if e.g. one source has connection problems, but uses timestamps to get the original order back). About the "font": it was actually a fun little brain teaser, so np :-)